# What is the correct procedure for a user who edits only the tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits, suggested-edits

I've noticed a recent trend in the edit queues on SO whereby a user finds a tag that they think is incorrect and 'corrects' it and then proceeds to go looking for all questions with this tag and edit them.
It seems like it's more a method of increasing reputation than of actually improving the question.

It also, IMO, spams the edit queue, having 10 questions needing approval because of a tag change.

What is the preferred procedure for handling this?